# Finding where elements in a list fall in specific range within another list

Tags: python, list, loops, range

Let's say I have:

```
l1=[0, 0.01, 0.03, 0.08, 0.13]
l2=[0, 0.03, 0.09, 0.15]
```

I need some kind of loop (while or for) to check a condition: check values in `l1` that fall in a specific range (inclusive) within `l2` and print out the upper bound of that range.

Output should look like: `[0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.09, 0.15]`.

For example, the first value in `l1` is 0 and it falls in the 0-0.03 category of `l2`, so print the upper bound of this range, i.e. 0.03. Next, 0.01 falls in the same range so print 0.03 again. Third, 0.03 is also in the same range so print the same upper bound of 0.03 (since it needs to be inclusive). Fourth, 0.08 falls in the 0.03-0.09 range of `l2` so print 0.09. The last value is .13 which is in the 0.09 to 0.15 range so print 0.15.

P.S. I'll need to modify the code such that if `l1` started at a value less than `l2[0]`, I'd still want to to use 0.03 as the upper bound as it is the least upper bound in `l2`. Likewise, if last value of `l1` is greater than `l2[-1]`, continue to print the greatest upperbound given in `l2`.

Ideally this needs to work for any length of `l1` and `l2`. Thanks.

I have tried something like:

```
for indx_l1, val_l1 in enumerate(l1):
    for indx_l2, val_l2 in enumerate(l2):
        while val_l1<val_l2:
            print(val_l2)
```

but this is giving me an infinite loop since its only checking the first value instead of iterating through. I also need that iteration to break after checking all the values within `l1` that fall within the corresponding ranges of `l2`.

Comment: Please update your question with what you’ve tried so far, and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: values inside the while loop are never changing that's why you are getting infinite loop

Comment: Right, is there any way to iterate through them instead? I thought the for loop would help with that. Not sure if that requires another loop?

Comment: a simple solution would be sort the second list and use for loop to check the upperbound

Comment: The second list is already sorted

Comment: as per your conditions for 0 output should be 0 why 0.03?

Comment: I need the ranges to come in pairs: [0, 0.03], [0.03, 0.09], [0.09, 0.15]. 0.03 represents the upper bound of the first range and 0 is within [0,0.03]

Comment: what about this "Output should look like: 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.09, 0.15, 0.15"? You have to mention correct expected output

Comment: It's because you are iterating `l1` against these ranges from `l2`. Print the upper bound of these ranges for every element in `l1` that falls within their corresponding range. See, "For example..." to explain the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lists, loop each element in `l1` and check the smallest number that is larger than that element:

```
[min([y if (y-x)>=0 else l2[-1] for y in l2[1:]]) for x in l1]
#[0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.09, 0.15]
```

This takes care of both cases where `l1` has lower than `l2[0]` and higher than `l2[-1]` values as you wished.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the effort. First few elements of my real data set are: `l1=[0.0, 0.0027397260273972603, 0.00821917808219178, 0.019178082191780823]` and `l2=[0.002777777777777778, 0.041666666666666664, 0.08333333333333333, 0.12222222222222222]`. I think your first solution worked well: `[min(l2, key=lambda i:i if (i-x)>=0 else float('inf')) for x in l1]` which outputs `[.00277..,.00277...,..0416...,.0416]` but your new solution just prints .0416... for all.

Comment: I see that the original solution however does not take the last value of `l2` if the last element in `l1` is greater (instead it defaults back to the minimum of `l2`) but your new one does. Only problem with the new one is for some reason its skipping the first element in `l2` which should get outputted for the first few values of `l1`.

Comment: Didn't you want _if l1 started at a value less than l2[0], I'd still want to to use 0.03 as the upper bound as it is the least upper bound in l2_? Does it not mean the first element of `l2` should not be returned at all? Maybe you can clarify a bit. Thank you

Comment: And for you previous comment, it should turn 0.0416 according to your question specification, unless again I do not understand the question clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake that was due to some other calculation in my code. Your code works perfectly, thanks for the help!